# Options for network file systems for Linux Systems

Tags: linux, debian, nfs, nas

I want to learn about the available options for network file systems with Linux.

So far I am aware of

- open afs
- nsf (network filesystem ?)
- samba (windows share)
- NAS (in the form of NAS specific OS eg Freenas, this might technically be a seperate thing)

Are there any resources (wiki pages etc) which give an overview of the various network filesystem options available for Linux servers?

This is an area I am pretty much completely new to and currently have minimal experience with.

I presume, but don't know, if this is entirely seperated from RAID configurations. It might be a case by case basis kind of thing.

What do I want to achieve?

I have an old machine which I want to use as a fileserver. I would like to be able to boot my Debian workstation and have additional volumes appear mounted as if they are on the local machine however are actually on a remote machine connected via the network.

Answer (score 0):

NAS is basically dedicated NFS/SMB/(maybe AFS) boxes with maybe a beginner oriented GUI as an administration interface.

A NAS box can be a front to a SAN storage based solution (think multiple say 4 NFS servers which uses FC to communicate with a ZFS (for example) system.)

Differentiate between NAS and SAN. NAS always distributes access to a file system hierarchy while SAN is about disks.